# request-promise headers correnction problem in vs code

Tags: javascript

I've spent about 4h searching for this problem but it seems no one faced it before ??

See... I'm learning web scraping and for that I'm using **request** & **request-promise** in vscode.
the problem is when I try to set the default headers :

see this image : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQONs.png)

**vscode automatically corrects it** into, by removing '' :

see this image : [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMR2E.png)

I wanna know why is this happening & how to fix it ?

tnx in advance :)

Comment: "how to fix it ?" — It isn't broken.

Comment: I mean what's making vscode remove the '' ? I tought the headers should be writen as following : headers { 
"header":"value"
}

Comment: disable plugin like eslint, prettier

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code, which vscode, generates is not broken.
Since `accept` could be used as a normal object key without any quoting it removes the quotes.
A manual how to disable this could be found here: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-atom/issues/292

Comment: so you're saying the fact that vscode removed the quotes won't have an effect on the properties, right ?

Comment: Yep ;) If you're doing `{ x: 123 }` or  `{ "x": 123 }` has no difference. This ofc does not only applies to valid variable names. Something like `{ x-y: 123 }` will not work.

Comment: Okay, I understand now